# Toggle 'data-property' with a button & jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I have a full screen youtube video as a background of a website that I'm working on and I'm trying to add a mute/unmute toggle with a button. This is how I'm pulling in the video :

```
<a id="bgndVideo" class="player" data-property="{videoURL:'https://youtu.be/KW2JUfgQct0',containment:'.video-section', quality:'high', autoPlay:true, mute:true, opacity:1}">bg</a>
```

I know the logic of how I'd like to run the toggle, when the buttons clicked I would like the data property to change, so if its data-property is mute:true onClick I would like it to change to mute:false and then back when clicked again.

this is what I've tried -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".muteButton").click( function (){
    $(this).data('mute', !$(this).data('mute'));
});

});
```

with an anchor tag -

```
<a class="muteButton" href="#">Mute</a>
```

I've looked up how to do this but had no luck, I've never written jquery so I'm lost, is this an easy thing to do??

Thanks

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: thats all I have ... if you read the question you can see what I'm asking

Comment: See, that's the thing, your question as it stands is just a request for free work. If you want to hire a programmer: do so. If you have a specific problem with your code that you'd like an answer to, I recommend editing your question to include the code that you're attempting to use, and update the question to be around the specific piece that you're struggling with. Otherwise, as it stands [this question is off topic (#1)](/help/on-topic).

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 
 $(".muteButton").click( function (){
    $(this).data('mute', !$(this).prop('mute'));
});
 
});

Comment: thats what I'm trying thats npot working

Answer (score 0):

The data property of bgndVideo is not valid json syntax. so, its treating as string.

```
<a id='bgndVideo' class='player' data-property='{"videoURL":"https://youtu.be/KW2JUfgQct0" , "containment":".video-section", "quality":"high", "autoPlay":true, "mute":true, "opacity":1}'>bg</a> 
<a class="muteButton btn btn-default" href="#">Click me to Mute</a>
<div id="muteValueDiv"></div><br>
<div id="bgndVideoDataPropDiv"></div>
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(".muteButton").click(function () {

                $(bgndVideo).data('property').mute = !$(bgndVideo).data('property').mute;

                $('#muteValueDiv').html('After negation Mute Value is - ' + $(bgndVideo).data('property').mute);

                $('#bgndVideoDataPropDiv').html('After updating data property, data property is ' + JSON.stringify( $(bgndVideo).data('property')));
     });
});
```

Please refer jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/u89oexea