# Change sound from mute to un mute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, toggle

I'm trying to toggle that data property of a youtube video, this is the HTML I currently have

```
<a id="bgndVideo" class="player" data-property="{videoURL:'https://youtu.be/KW2JUfgQct0',containment:'.video-section', quality:'high', autoPlay:true, mute:true, opacity:1}">bg</a>

<a class="muteButton" href="#">Mute</a>
```

I'm trying to change the data property from "mute:true" to "mute:false"

I found a tutorial where this was working, but instead of data it said prop

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

     $(".muteButton").click( function (){
        $(this).data('mute', !$(this).data('mute'));
    });

    });
```

This worked well in the tutorial I found but nothing happens when I add this to the site, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Its duplicate of [Toggle 'data-property' with a button & jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876264/toggle-data-property-with-a-button-jquery/35898628#35898628)

```
<a id='bgndVideo' class='player' data-property='{"videoURL":"https://youtu.be/KW2JUfgQct0" , "containment":".video-section", "quality":"high", "autoPlay":true, "mute":true, "opacity":1}'>bg</a> 
<a class="muteButton btn btn-default" href="#">Click me to Mute</a>
<div id="muteValueDiv"></div><br>
<div id="bgndVideoDataPropDiv"></div>
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(".muteButton").click(function () {

                $(bgndVideo).data('property').mute = !$(bgndVideo).data('property').mute;

                $('#muteValueDiv').html('After negation Mute Value is - ' + $(bgndVideo).data('property').mute);

                $('#bgndVideoDataPropDiv').html('After updating data property, data property is ' + JSON.stringify( $(bgndVideo).data('property')));
     });
});
```

Comment: I apologize, I asked this right as you answered the other, which had no responses. I tried this and it didn't work, thank you though!

Comment: actually, you need to fix the json syntax of bgndVideo data property. That is the first step. The current json (which is in your post) is not being interpreted as json object when you try to print to console: console.log( $(bgndVideo).data('property')). Javascript treating this as string instead of json object. Please refer jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u89oexea/

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.. it updates the mute attribute and replace with new mute attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $(".muteButton").click( function (){
    var a= $('#bgndVideo').data('property');
            a.mute=!a.mute;
    alert($('#bgndVideo').data('property').mute);
    alert(JSON.stringify(a));
    $(".id").html('<a id="bgndVideo" class="player" data-property='+JSON.stringify(a)+'>bg</a>')
  });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="id">
 <a id="bgndVideo" class="player" data-property='{"videoURL": "https://youtu.be/KW2JUfgQct0", "containment": ".video-section", "quality":"high", "autoPlay":true, "mute":true, "opacity":1}'>bg</a>
</div>
<a class="muteButton" href="#">Mute</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/